# Can't get the right cell of EKEventEditViewController

Tags: swift

```
func test(button:UIButton){

    var alarm = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: 20)
    var event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
    event.title = "xxxx"
    event.startDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 20)
    event.endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1000)
    event.calendar = calendarWithName(cal_name)
    event.alarms = [alarm]

    var ev = EKEventEditViewController()
    ev.event = event
    ev.eventStore = store
    ev.editViewDelegate = self
    ev.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(ev, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    if (viewController.isKindOfClass(UITableViewController.self)){

        var tableview =  (viewController as UITableViewController).tableView

        println(tableview.numberOfSections())

        for i in 0...tableview.numberOfSections() {

              println(tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: i)) != nil)

        }
    }
}
```

i'm using EKEventEditViewDelegate , the willShowViewController func run well,i can get the right table, but i can't get the 5th and next sections,what's wrong with the code ,how can i fix this .

the console shows:

```
8

true

true

true

true

true

false

false

false

false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` only returns cells that are visible.

> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not
>   visible or indexPath is out of range.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: then how to disable a cell which out of range

Comment: To make sure the cell is visible you can use the method indexPathsForVisibleRows, something like this:

let indexPathsForVisibleRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as [NSIndexPath]
if find(indexPathsForVisibleRows, indexPath) != nil { // Do your stuff }

Comment: Thank you very much!I'll see the doc more carefully next time!